# Facing issues while migrating to Redis session state

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session, redis

I am changing the session management provider from inproc to Redis session state to resolve the shared session problem for Web Garden and for better performance of my MVC application. Problem with using Redis is that classes must be serialized before putting in the session which requires a lot of modifications in my existing solution. Is there any way to overcome this problem? Is there any provider which can be used for serializing the objects at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We went through such a change and there is no other way to do it. It is just marking your classes with an attribute, so it is not such a big thing.
The big thing can come when you find some types which are not serializable at all - like an Object and then you need to change it. Whenever you go with the session out of process everything must be serializable because they will go over the wire.
And by the way, you will not have better performance, nothing compares to saving the data in process. On our side we noticed an additional ~4-500ms for each request - just to load and save data to Redis. But there are other big advantages, like autoscaling. 
Also pay attention that if you save something really big in session, it can timeout - check the throwOnError parameter for the redis session provider. It will actually be better to cache big items (store them directly in redis) then to save them in Session, so they will not be loaded and saved for each request.

Comment: Answer from @lcostea is correct, you'll just need to do the work if you want to be able to scale out your application across multiple app servers.  There's no magic here.